# REACTDOM is not exported from react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build my project of React, but the console throw this:

> *Failed to compile. Attempted import error: 'ReactDOM' is not exported from 'react' (imported as 'ReactDOM').*

This is my package.json

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GBdE.jpg)

this is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";

import "./index.css"; import App from "./App";
     
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: If you use `yarn` - what's the output of `yarn why react`? Ensure it only shows one version of React. For `npm` there's a similar command, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 4):

import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import React from "react"
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error could suggest that you might not have react installed. I would suggest deleting your *node_modules* folder and `package-lock.json` file and running `npm i` in the terminal.

Comment: Running `npm ci` is a better, efficient & short alternative to this process.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).